# Build new dictionary from what is not in list

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I need to compare a list to dictionary values and build a new dictionary with values that don't exist in the old dictionary.

```
olddict = {'user': ['group1', 'group2'],
        'user2': ['group1']}

RequiredGroups = ['group1', 'group2','group3', 'group4']

newdict= {}
for groups in RequiredGroups:
    for key, value in olddict.items():
        if groups not in value:
            newdict[key] = groups
print(newdict)
```

current output

```
{'user2': 'group4', 'user': 'group4'}
```

desired output

```
{'user': ['group3', 'group4'],
'user2': ['group2', 'group3', 'group4']}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### To modify your solution:

Instead of:

```
newdict[key] = groups
```

Use:

```
newdict.setdefault(key, []).append(groups)
```

Full code:

```
olddict = {'user': ['group1', 'group2'],
        'user2': ['group1']}

RequiredGroups = ['group1', 'group2','group3', 'group4']

newdict= {}
for groups in RequiredGroups:
    for key, value in olddict.items():
        if groups not in value:
            newdict.setdefault(key, []).append(groups)
print(newdict)
```

Output:

```
{'user2': ['group2', 'group3', 'group4'], 'user': ['group3', 'group4']}
```

### A shorter solution:

It could be much easier with a dictionary comprehension one-liner though:

```
>>> {k: [x for x in RequiredGroups if x not in v] for k, v in olddict.items()}
{'user': ['group3', 'group4'], 'user2': ['group2', 'group3', 'group4']}
>>>
```

Comment: `map` is utterly pointless here. You have a habit of forcing a functional approach when it is completely unnecessary and only serves to increase the overhead and make the code unreadable.